# How can I pass a String variable to getStringArray please

Tags: android

```
        void spinnerArraySet (String st) {
            Spinner spinner2 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner2);
            spinner2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            ArrayAdapter arr = new ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, getResources().getStringArray(R.array.st));
            spinner2.setAdapter(arr);
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The parameter type of [getStringArray](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources#getStringArray(int)) is **int**, so you need firstly convert the String array name to an int identifier.

you could refer [getIdentifier](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources#getIdentifier(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)) to get detailed info, but below is an example:

```
void spinnerArraySet (String st){
    int arrayID = getResources().getIdentifier(st, "array", this.getPackageName());
    String[] items = getResources().getStringArray(arrayID);
}
```

Comment: It works great now, thank you for your help.

Comment: If the answer helps you, please accept it,  thanks!